# GestureDetector can’t detect touch action on free space

Tags: flutter

I'd like to make all the free spase in a widget clicable i.e. all the free space in the raw

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        ...
      );
    },
    child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SampleImage(image1),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('some text'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
)
```

But some free space still isn't clicable.

[image]

How to achive that?

Comment: change `GestureDetector.behavior` - by default it is `deferToChild`

Comment: @pskink it did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs it says

> By default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches;
> this behavior can be controlled with [behavior].

That's why that empty space doen't catch a touch action.

Adding `behavior` property with `opaque` enum should solve the issue.

```
GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
```